# Importing ShapeFiles into Oracle XE

Tags: oracle, spatial, shapefile, oracle-xe

I'm looking to import one of the Shapefiles supplied with the Ordnance Survey Boundary-Line opensource set into Oracle XE.

http://data.gov.uk/dataset/os-boundary-line

Unfortunately I'm completely unsure how to go about this, despite much Googling.

Anyone got any pointers or tips or a link to a guide?

Cheers

James

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle Shapefile Converter - near the bottom of the page

http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/spatial/index.html